# How to stop Workplace app's notification sound in Alarm & Calls only (DND) mode?

Tags: 8.0-oreo, do-not-disturb

Although I've set "Do not disturb/Priority only/Alarm & Call", Workplace app still "ting ting" everytime someone chat with me.

How can I make my Sony Xperia XA1 Plus (Android 8) to a "profile" that everything should be silenced except Alarm and Call?

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Check in the settings of that app. Disable from there. Some apps override e global settings. This may be the case

Comment: the app has no setting to "disable notification" :(

Comment: @beeshyams but it really shame on android when some app could replace `global` setting :(

Comment: I have heard Facebook does that but can't confirm since I don't use it. Yes, it is undesirable